# Sqlalchemy Core create table with UniqueConstraint and condition

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**DB=postgresql**

there is a table created using this syntax

```
event_invites = Table(
    "event_invites",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column("from_user", ForeignKey(users.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("to_user", ForeignKey(users.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("to_event", ForeignKey(events.c.id, ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False),
    Column(
        "is_active",
        Boolean(),
        server_default=sql.expression.true(),
        nullable=True,
    ),
    ....
    ....
    UniqueConstraint('from_user', 'to_user', 'to_event', 'is_active', name='unique_event_invites')
)
```

I need to add it so that the uniqueness of the fields is only triggered if the `is_active` field is `True`.

I have found a way to add this condition when creating tables with syntax for Sqlalchemy ORM

example

```
class ExampleTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'example_table'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            'ix_unique_primary_content',  # Index name
            'object_type', 'object_id',  # Columns which are part of the index
        unique=True,
        postgresql_where=Column('is_primary')),  # The condition
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    object_type = Column(Unicode(50))
    object_id = Column(Integer)
    is_primary = Column(Boolean)
```

But I can't figure out how to adapt it for my case

Something like this

```
UniqueConstraint('from_user', 'to_user', 'to_event', 'is_active', name='unique_event_invites',
                 postgresql_where=Column("is_active=True")
                 )
```

Return erorr

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'postgresql_where' is not accepted by dialect 'postgresql' on behalf of <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.UniqueConstraint'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Index](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html?highlight=index#sqlalchemy.schema.Index) with unique=True

```
event_invites = Table(
    "event_invites",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column("from_user", ForeignKey(users.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("to_user", ForeignKey(users.c.id, ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=False),
    Column("to_event", ForeignKey(events.c.id, ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False),
    Column(
        "is_active",
        Boolean(),
        server_default=sql.expression.true(),
        nullable=True,
    ),
    ....
    ....
        Index("unique_event_invites", "from_user", "to_user", "to_event", "is_active", unique=True,
          postgresql_where=Column("is_active='True'"))
)
```